# how to replace the last end of line symbol of a multiline string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to replace the last end of line symbol '$' of a multiline Ruby string using regular expressions. The following code replaces the first one, but that's not what I want:

```
string.sub!(/$/, "replace")
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? An example of input and expected output would help.

Comment: Wait, do you have literal '$' characters in your strings, or newlines? As @undur_gongor says, you really should show sample input and desired output. We're all just guessing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str1 = "hello\nworld\nsexytime"
str2 = "hello\nworld\nsexytime\n"

puts str1.sub(/(\n.+)\z/,'LAST\\1')
#=> hello
#=> worldLAST
#=> sexytime

puts str2.sub(/(\n.*)\z/,'LAST\\1')
#=> hello
#=> world
#=> sexytimeLAST
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foo = "first$line $
second$line $
third$line $"

foo.gsub! /\$$/, "replace"    
puts foo

# =>
first$line replace
second$line replace
third$line replace
```

It replaces your $ symbol (because this have special meaning for regexp, you have to escape it) in the end of the line (and therefore you use second $ symbol). And if you have to prepare several replacement, use `gsub` method - `sub` make it only once.

Comment: The result, I'm trying to achieve is
# =>
first$line
second$line
third$line replace. 
Each line at new line, sorry for the markup

Comment: You need to get rid of all '$' except the last one? and that last one should be replaced with custom string?

Comment: It must be something like Phrogz's solution. Thanks for the advice, my explanation was terrible :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string.sub!(/\n?\z/, 'replace')
```